# Equivalent of java's Optional.ifPresent in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

Does C# have the equivalent of Java's Optional.ifPresent? I'm hoping for something added to the Nullable type.

First glance seems to indicate there isn't anything.

Is there a more elegant way for running something on a nullable type when it is present than:

```
Guid? alias1 = // Get potentially null guid

if (alias1.HasValue)
{
    DoProcessingWithValue(alias1.Value);
}
```

In java I can do:

```
Optional<Guid> alias1 = // Get optional containing Guid

alias1.ifPresent(value -> DoProcessingWithValue(value));
```

Comment: I am not aware of a 1:1 equivalent, but you could make an extension method like `public static void IfPresent(this Guid? value, Action<Guid> theAction) { if(value.HasValue) theAction(value.Value); }` or use an Expression instead of the Action to make it even more similar.

Comment: Personally, testing for `null` in an `if` seems more declarative, `ifPresent` seems a bit, well... meh,,,

Comment: ^^ https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8rych

Comment: It's not built into the language. But there are some libraries available as Nuget packages with similar capabilities like:
OneOf<T1, T2, T3...> https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf and
Optional.Option<T> https://github.com/nlkl/Optional